# Python: ImportError: No module named xxx even after performing pip install

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working to install the project https://github.com/wavefrontHQ/python-client and test it:

```
edamame$ pip install wavefront_client
Requirement already satisfied: wavefront_client in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3>=1.15 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from wavefront_client)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from wavefront_client)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from wavefront_client)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from wavefront_client)
```

Here is my `test.py`:

```
import wavefront_api_client
import path.to.wavefront_api_client
import wavefront_api_client as wave_api

base_url = 'https://YOUR_INSTANCE.wavefront.com'
api_key = 'YOUR_API_TOKEN'

config = wave_api.Configuration()
config.host = base_url
client = wave_api.ApiClient(configuration=config, header_name='Authorization', header_value='Bearer ' + api_key)

# instantiate source API
source_api = wave_api.SourceApi(client)
sources = source_api.get_all_source()
print sources
```

But I got the error:

```
edameme$ python test.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
        import wavefront_api_client
    ImportError: No module named wavefront_api_client
```

If I do sys.print at the beginning of the file, I got:

I got: `['/Users/edamame/Documents/git/python_wave', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC']`

Why am I getting this error even I already installed wavefront_api_client? Thanks!

Comment: Do `pip` and `python` point to the same Python installation? Try printing `sys.path` at the top of your script, before your `import`.

Comment: Check your ``pip --version``

Comment: @kichik: I add the output pf sys.path in the original question (too long for the comment)

Comment: use /usr/local/bin/pythonw2.7 test.py and worked. Thanks!

Comment: Better use `virtualenv` or `pipenv` to manage your Python version and modules.